# django rest framework and multiple routers

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have an application with an API created with DRF. In that i use a DRF-router to route the URL's. I want to add a route to the list-view with parameters (so @list_route won't work) to certain viewsets, but not to others.

So i wanted to define two routers:

```
user_router = routers.SimpleRouter()
admin_router = routers.SimpleRouter()
```

I want a route added to *one* of them:

```
search_route = Route(
    url='^{prefix}/search/(?P<field>\w+)/(?P<value>\w+){trailing_slash}$',
    mapping={
        'get': 'search',
    },
    name='{basename}-search',
    initkwargs={}
)

admin_router.routes.append(search_route)
```

But now i end up with the *search_route* added to both routers, and thus coupled to the viewsets i register in the routers individually.

```
ipython> user_router.routes
...
 Route(url='^{prefix}/search/(?P<field>\\w+)/(?P<method>\\w+)/(?P<keyword>\\w+){trailing_slash}$', mapping={'get': 'search'}, name='{basename}-search', initkwargs={'suffix': 'Search'}),
...
```

Why is this??? I am probably missing something basic here. How can i add a   Route() to certain routers but not to others, so that i can split up my API-urls in "user" and "admin" with each their own methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright, i figured it out. The SimpleRouter class in the Django Rest Framework defines the routes in the class, and doesn't bind the values in the `__init__` phase. `SimpleRouter.routes` is a `list`.

Since lists are mutable, all instances of `SimpleRouter` point at the same *route*-list when creating the SimpleRouter instances. When i appended a `Route` to `admin_router.routes`, it also updated `user_router.routes`....

The way to overcome this is to define separate `Router` classes which override the router-list.

```
class AdminRouter(SimpleRouter):
    routes = # [ ... my list of Route()'s ... ]


class UserRouter(SimpleRouter):
    routes = # [ ... my other list of Route()'s ...]


admin_router = AdminRouter()
user_router = UserRouter()
```